# C# WinForms: использование Chart для рисования гистограмм

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день!

**Дано:** Есть класс `InfoForBarChart`, который предоставляет `Chart'у` информацию для рисования гистограмм:

```
internal class InfoForBarChart
{
    public List<YData> Counts { get; private set; }

    public List<XData> IntervalTopBorders { get; private set; }

    public InfoForBarChart(List<YData> yData, List<XData> xData)
    {
        Counts = yData;
        IntervalTopBorders = xData;
    }
}
```

где `YData` и `XData` классы описаны следующим образом:

```
internal class XData
{
    public double TopBorderValue { get; set; }

    public XData(double topBorderValue)
    {
        TopBorderValue = topBorderValue;
    }
}

internal class YData
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public YData(int count)
    {
        Count = count;
    }
}
```

**Задача:** Необходимо построить гистограмму, где высота столбцов определялась бы из списка `Counts` класса `InfoForBarChart`, а значения по X - из списка `IntervalTopBorders`.

Пока реализация рисования у меня следующая:

```
chart1.DataSource = infoForDrawingBarChart.Counts; // Источник данных - список Counts
chart1.Series["CountsBar"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column; // Вертикальные столбцы
chart1.Series.Clear(); // Удаляем все столбцы
chart1.Series.Add("CountsBar").YValueMembers = "Count"; // Значение для каждого столбца берется из поля YData.Count      
chart1.Series["CountsBar"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
chart1.DataBind();
```

Гистограмма после построения выглядит так:

[image: BarChart]

**Что меня не устраивает:** Как видно из рисунка, столбцы гистограммы нумеруются от 1 до 20 (20 - это количество элементов списка `Counts`).

**Вопрос:** Можно ли как-то задать "нумерацию" этих столбцов, где источником данных для этой нумерации будет список `infoForDrawingBarChart.IntervalTopBorders`? Если есть, то подскажите, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myFirstChart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
```

С помощью этой строчки Вы можете задавать подписи (координаты по осям  OX и OY). То есть в случае гистограммы - подписи по горизонтальной оси и значения по вертикали. Первый аргумент - подпись, второй - значение.